# Manually change the table cell image view when click on table cell umageview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have an question.If i want to change the table cell image view image when click on the particular table cell image view. How to do this? Initially all the rows having same images in image view.

Comment: implement the change in tableviewDidselect method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. There you can add some checks and change whatever you need.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method for this. Set some flag for the selected cell from didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Check this flag in cellForRowAtIndexPath method while assigning the image to all cells and assign differnt image for the selected cell. 
You can then reload the table from didSelectRowAtIndexPath itself.

Hope this helps.